# How to put backtrack on a partition with Windows XP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backtrack

This is a similar question to my previous one.

I now am trying to get Backtrack5 onto a separate partition of my main hard drive with windows but the site says that I need a clean hard drive. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Just to clarify, the seperate partition is empty and windows is installed on a different partition on that hard drive?

Comment: yes i have my hard drive split into two partitions that way i can choose which os to boot from each time i start my machine @Anthon

Comment: Then you should update your question `main hard drive with windows` could mean there is only windows on it, and all partitions belong to it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably looked at the How to install to a harddisc documentation, you should be using use the [dual boot](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/dual-boot-install/) option (assuming your separate partition is not used by Windows, see comment).